# how to receive a stored procedure's result using object context?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, report

I have a stored procedure and I am working in VS10 entity framework. I want to call that stored procedure from my DAO but don't know how to receive the results. Anybody give idea please?

```
ConsentReleaseResult consentReleaseResult = new ConsentReleaseResult();
        try
        {
            using (PC2Entities objectContext = new PC2Entities())
            {
                var consent = objectContext.spGetConsentRelease(id);
            }
        }
        /* Handling Error Logging */
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
        }
```

I want to receive my result in "consentReleaseResult object". 
var consent = objectContext.spGetConsentRelease(id); throws an exception. Please guide me!

Comment: The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'PC2Entities.ConsentRelease'. A member of the type, 'Id', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.

Comment: You need to accept answers to your previous questions, that will improve it

Comment: pls answer my original question

Comment: I Hope [This helps you](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetentityframework/thread/3ccc1f17-589d-46ef-8df8-ab48abe2dfee) and [This too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227130/problem-with-entity-framework-after-adding-column-to-db-table)

Comment: Is your result an output parameter or a result set?

Comment: please see the code I posted in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the results from following syntax

```
 if (consent != null)
 {
     foreach(var r in consent)
     {
           r.[fieldname]
     }
 }
```

If your store procedure returns full table value then you can get the records as

```
foreeach(tablename r in consent)
{
    r.[fieldname]
}
```